# Access Violation - Associative Array

Tags: associative-array, access-violation, d, dmd

I get an access violation error at this:

```
classes[newClass.name] = newClass;
```

Full method code:

```
void initClass(Class newClass) {
    synchronized {
        auto classes = cast(Class[string])classDeclarations;
        classes[newClass.name] = newClass;
        classDeclarations = cast(shared(Class[string]))classes;
    }
}
```

classDeclarations is declared as this:

```
    private shared Class[string] classDeclarations;
```

It has worked at earlier state in my program though. Is it possible that the access violation is due to members of newClass or is it because of class. I know it usually would occure during invalid memory access, but shouldn't the casts throw the exception too?

Am I missing something?

newClass is not null, but it's declared as following:

```
class Class : Variable {
private:
bool hasInit = false; // when constructor is called this is set to true ...
public:
Class[string] bases;
Variable[string] variables;
Task[string] tasks;
string typeName; // class name, not var name ...

Task constructor;
Task destructor;

this() {
    super(VariableType.Class);
}

void setBaseData(Class baseClass) {
    foreach (var; baseClass.variables.values) {
        variables[var.name] = var;
    }
    foreach (task; baseClass.tasks.values) {
        tasks[task.name] = task;
    }
}

override bool isNull() {
    return hasInit;
}

override Class copy() {
    auto newClass = new Class;
    newClass.typeName = typeName;
    foreach (b; bases.values) {
        auto newBase = b.copy();
        newBase.name = b.name;
        newClass.bases[newBase.name] = newBase;
    }
    foreach (v; variables.values) {
        newClass.variables[v.name] = v.copy();
    }
    foreach (t; tasks.values) {
        newClass.tasks[t.name] = t.copy();
    }
    newClass.typeName = typeName;
    newClass.mutable = mutable;
    newClass.constructor = constructor.copy();
    newClass.destructor = destructor.copy();
    return newClass;
}

override int sizeOf() {
    int res = 0;
    foreach (b; bases.values)
        res += b.sizeOf();
    foreach (v; variables.values)
        res += v.sizeOf();
    return res;
}
}
```

I was thinking it might be some of the members of Class? I have no idea though, to be honest.

initClass is called like this and all the data is initialized.

```
auto newClass = new Class;
                    newClass.name = tokenizer.name;
                    newClass.typeName = tokenizer.name;
                    foreach (base; tokenizer.baseNames) {
                        if (classExists(base)) {
                            auto baseClass = getNewClass(base);
                            baseClass.name = base;
                            newClass.bases[base] = baseClass;
                            newClass.setBaseData(baseClass);
                        }
                    }
                    initClass(newClass);
```

I hope to resolve this. In case I resolve it myself, I'll post it either as an answer or comment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Found the issue, it wasn't related to that. It just didn't happen when I declared the line, but it was at another call to it.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer too so people who search for this will see it? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was 2 members of the Class class which were null. I was trying to access them somewhere else. The reason I thought it was related to the adding was simply that I didn't call the class that other place when it wasn't added to the collection.